# C server-client communication via socket - how to print message from server to client

Tags: c, sockets, server, client, communication

I have a problem with my server. He cannot send basic message to client.
I think that problem is in client because he cannot receive sent message but I dont know how to solve this problem :/

My server:

```
int server(){
  int lis_soc,s,r;
  struct sockaddr_un ad;
  char buffer[MAXSIZE];

  lis_soc=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  memset(&ad,0,sizeof(ad));
  ad.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(ad.sun_path,"./sock");

  unlink("./sock");
  bind(lis_soc,(struct sockaddr *) &ad,sizeof(ad));
  listen(lis_soc,10);
  s=accept(lis_soc,0,0);
  while(strcmp(buffer,"halt")!=0 && strcmp(buffer,"quit")!=0){
      char *pch=(char *)malloc(MAXSIZE);

    bzero(buffer,MAXSIZE);
    r=read(s,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(pch,buffer);
    strtok(pch," ");

    if(strcmp(buffer,"help")==0) get_help(s);  //this is the funcion for print from server
    else if(strcmp(buffer,"info")==0) get_info();
    else if(strcmp(buffer,"run")==0) run();
    else if(strcmp(pch,"ls")==0){
      if(strcmp(buffer,"ls")==0) ls(".",NULL);
      else while ((pch = strtok (NULL, " ")) != NULL) {ls(pch,NULL);}
    }
    else system(buffer);
  }
  close(s);
  printf("SERVER END OF CONNECTION\n");
  return 0;
}
```

My client:

```
int client(){
    int s,r;
    char buffer[MAXSIZE];
    char output[]="client: Enter data for server: ";
  struct sockaddr_un ad;

  s=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  memset(&ad,0,sizeof(ad));
  ad.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(ad.sun_path,"./sock");

  connect(s,(struct sockaddr *) &ad,sizeof(ad));
  while(strcmp(buffer,"halt")!=0 && strcmp(buffer,"quit")!=0){
    bzero(buffer,MAXSIZE);
    write(1,output,strlen(output));
    r=read(0,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[r-1]='\0';
    write(s,buffer,strlen(buffer));
  }
  close(s);
  printf("CLIENT END OF CONNECTION\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Function get_help() called from the server:

```
void get_help(int lis_soc){
  char buffer[]="Ahoj client";
  write(lis_soc,&buffer,strlen(buffer));
}
```

after the call of my function get help nothing was printed. Why?

Comment: You MUST completely and correctly handle the result returned from all system calls like 'connect()' and 'read()'.

Comment: I edited my code correctly but nothing wrong happened everything is running properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code doesn't read the message it gets from the server.

I compiled and executed your code to double check that this is the problem.

Simply add a `read(s, ...);` call at the end of the client's while loop:

```
while(strcmp(buffer,"halt")!=0 && strcmp(buffer,"quit")!=0){
    bzero(buffer,MAXSIZE);
    write(1,output,strlen(output));
    r=read(0,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[r-1]='\0';
    write(s,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    read(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Answer from server: %s\n",buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was the problem. :)

Comment: 'buffer[r-1]='\0'' splats the last char received.